# How can I scroll the browser window?

Tags: xpages

I am validating my form using an extension pages dialog box.  I popup the dialog box with the error message when the user needs to correct input.

The dialog box has an OK button that closes the dialog box and sets focus to the field that needs to be corrected.

```
 var ef = dojo.byId(errorField);
 ef.focus();
```

This is working great except......

I have a group of buttons and a bunch of other components that float to the top of the form.

They are inside a panel with the following CSS.

```
 .PNCToolBar2 {
position:fixed;
top:68px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
height:40px;
color:#fff;
background-color:#F2F2F2;
padding-top:6.0px;
padding-left:15.0px
 }
```

What is happening is that if the failing field is scrolled up under the "button bar"   then the  browser scrolls a bit to try to get the button into focus but not enough.  Depending on how the user had their browser scrolled on the form, all or part of the field in error might still be hidden by the button bar.

Is there a way to first know if the field is at the top of the browser window under the bar and then scoll a bit if it is to make the field appear?   If so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
dojo.window.scrollIntoView(ef);
```

If the DOM node represented by ef is not currently on the screen, Dojo will scroll just enough so that it will be.

[More info on this method](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/window/scrollIntoView.html)

Comment: That did not work.  Remember it is "in view".  It is just under a floating panel.

Comment: Got this to work.  It was real simple.  All I did was to scroll to 0,0 then set the focus.

Answer (score 0):

using javascript you can use the scrollTo() method
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp

Comment: This seems like it would work but how would I get the position of a field?  What I would need to do here is to set the focus to the field, get it's x axis, get it's y axis if it is under the bar then add 100px or so to it.   Then scroll to those coordinates.

Comment: Oops commented on the wrong post above.   I used the scroll method Adrian suggested above. Scrolled to 0,0 then set the focus.  It put the field in view always.  Reallly simple